# SIM800L GSM Module, no network signal RSSI

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, gsm, communication

I am using a GSM 800L module to send SMS messages. When I test the module with Arduino, it shows a 0 : -115dbm signal strength.

So basically there is no signal. SIM800L is a quad-band GSM/GPRS module that works on frequencies GSM850MHz, EGSM900MHz, DSC1800Mhz, and PCS1900MHz.

My SIM card carrier uses the frequency bands GSM 900, GSM 1800 for 2G-capablities.

What might be the possible reasons my GSM module doesn't work properly with my SIM card? I have tried different locations, still no signal.

The code I use for testing is provided by [Adafruit-Fona](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-fona-mini-gsm-gprs-cellular-phone-module.pdf).

Comment: Where do you live? 2G has been switched off in some countries.

Comment: Check antenna cable/connection, maybe shorted?

Comment: there is no cable for the antenna. I don't really what is the problem

Comment: Please can you accept your own answer (using the green tick below the voting buttons) in order to remove your question from the unanswered list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that I used 5 V Dc to power the module , it worked but in order to function I must use lithium battery. ( its mentioned in the manual)

Comment: Please can you accept your own answer (using the green tick below the voting buttons) in order to remove your question from the unanswered list. Thank you.